# Splitting a floating point number into a sum of two other numbers, without rounding errors

Tags: split, floating-point, floating-accuracy

I don't know if it is possible to do this, but i need to split a floating point number in sum of two number...

For example assuming *x* is a floating point number and we want to split this in
*x = I + f*, where *I* is the signed integer part while *f* is the signed fractional part, both floating number i guess such split could be implemented exactly (i.e. without fp error i mean).

I was wondering if it is possible to split somehow *x = (I-1.0) + (f + 1.0)*, namely without floating point rounding error.

I've implemented on my own the split *x = I + f* then summing and adding 1.0 i have the second split i presented, but basically it's affected from floating point rounding error such operation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(using double-precision for the examples)

> I was wondering if it is possible to split somehow x = (I-1.0) + (f + 1.0), namely without floating point rounding error.

There is no chance of obtaining such a split for all values. Take `0x1.0p-60`, the integral part of which is `0.0` and the fractional part is `0x1.0p-60`. `f + 1.0` is inexact and produces `1.0`, whereas `I-1.0` is exact and produces `-1.0`.

It's not just that the addition in `f + 1.0` is inexact: the floating-point value such that, when added `-1.0`, produces `0x1.0p-60`, does not exist.

A floating-point value `v` can always be split exactly into the sum of `fmod(v, 1.0)` and `v - fmod(v, 1.0)`, where the latter is an integer, and there is at least another way to split `v` exactly between an integer part and a fractional part using [IEEE 754 “Floating-point remainder”](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985#Standard_operations), which is subtly distinct from `fmod`, but there is no way to split numbers close to 0 into the floating-point sum of `1.0` and another value.